R Script for Power Bi SHA256 incorrect hash value
I used below R script code in Power BI for getting SHA256 encyrption however getting in correct value
Code:
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

library(digest)

len \<- length(dataset\[\[1\]\])

hash \<- c()

for (i in 1:len) 
{
hash \<- append(hash, digest::hmac(dataset\[i, 1\],dataset\[i, 2\], algo="sha256", serialize=F))
}
dataset$hash \<- hash

result \<- dataset

Correct Outcome for
abc@gmail.com is:

48ddb93f0b30c475423fe177832912c5bcdce3cc72872f8051627967ef278e08

however, I'm getting below hashed value:

a607834d59742c08da6ea80c3ecc4985decd1e3223129051c4f4eefc2cd5859f

